# Convert BigInt to Macaddr in Postgress

Tags: postgresql

I have a client table that has IP and macaddr saved as BIGINT.

I was able to convert IP to text with ::inet, how do I transform BIGINT to macaddr?

Example of MACaddr as saved: 8796349528980

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your BIGINT to HEX, and abuse the macddr type of postgresql to format that, like that:

```
SELECT TO_HEX(8796349528980)::macaddr;
```